# I have usually liked

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, present-simple

I found these sentences on the site where the grammar rules about the use of present perfect were explained:

- **I have usually liked** the people I **worked** with.
- **I have usually liked** the people I **have worked** with.

Can I say : **I have usually liked** the people I **work** with?
Or it is not grammatically correct and it is more correct to say : I usually **like** the people I **work** with?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Have usually [verb]_ implies a habitude in the past, so it would be odd to use it of current work colleagues.

Comment: But if I will say 'always' instead of 'usually': "I have always loved the people I work with"? Can I use the present simple in this case or not ?

Comment: Yes, if you mean your current colleagues and not all the people you have ever worked with.

Comment: I'm retired, but even so, I'd almost certainly just say ***I usually like the people I work with***. At a pinch, maybe I'd explicitly cast it into the past if I specifically wanted to call attention to the fact that I no longer work with people: ***I usually liked the people I worked with***. But why bother with a ***perfect*** form here at all? And even if you did start with Present Perrfect ***In the past I have usually liked...***, there's rarely any good reason to *continue* using more complex verb forms, so it's best to just continue with Simple Past ***...the people I worked with***.